# How to switch the language of the Struts2?

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I use Struts2 and Struts2-Jquery, for example to preper my calendar I do this.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<sj:datepicker id="fecini" name="oferta.finiOferta"
                placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" displayFormat="yy-mm-dd" minDate="0"
                data-mask="99/99/9999" />
```

But the calendar show me the names of months and days in English (by default), i need to show it in Spanish.

What can i do in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The `<sj:head>` tag allows you to set locale. Use `locale.language` OGNL expression to get current language.

```
<sj:head locale="%{locale.language}" />
```

Comment: Do I have download some extra lib o something, or that came with struts2, cause I changed it as another locale, for example <sj:head locale="fr" /> or <sj:head locale="de" /> but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to reload the page, use ctrl+F5.

Comment: I know, i do it to clean the cache, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JesusAlvarez: Which version of struts2-jquery-plugin?

Comment: struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.0.jar

Comment: @JesusAlvarez: Works for me. Maybe you have some errors, check console.